# Using LINQ to query xml to populate a .NET nested DataContract

Tags: .net, linq

I have the following .net fiddle code and was wondering if someone could kindly point me in the correct direction to why  I can't use the nested Type.Number or Type.Description definitions in the Linq query. I'm doing something incorrect, but don't know what. Tnx.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
                string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
                    <class number='1'>
                        <catch>English</catch>
                        <type number='1'>
                            <catch>data</catch>
                        </type>
                        <section number='1'>
                            <catch>data</catch>
                        </section>
                    </class>";

                XElement element= XElement.Parse(xml);
                List<Class> Classes = ( from t in element.Descendants("class")
                    select new Class()
                    {
                         Type.Number = t.Element("type").Attribute("number").Value,
                         Type.Description = t.Element("catch").Value,
                         Section.Number = t.Element("class").Attribute("number").Value,
                         Section.Description = t.Element("catch").Value,
                   }).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Class
        {
            public ClassType Type { get; set; }
            public Class()
            {
                Type = new ClassType();
                Section = new ClassType();
            }
        }
        public class ClassType
        {
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

```
.Select(c =>
            {
                var cl = new Class();
                cl.Type.Number = ...;

                return cl;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The xml I receive doesn't have a root node, so I'll have to deal that. But your code isn't going to work =) The query doesn't even make use the Class base object plus Catch is not even a class datatype. I need to reference the Class.Type.Number and Class.Section.Number types. I modified my question since I'm going to have other nested classes within the base class of Class, so I wanted to present the exact issue I had. <Section> might not always be there though in the xml, so I need to account for that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Wildview, in this case, can you provide workable example.

Comment: We'll that's the point, mine doesn't work hence the post. Your's doesn't appear to work either, I tried it in .net fiddle.

Comment: Ok sorry, I see your point. Sorry for the confusion. I can't post my actual code, so I just constructed something that was similar, so I could figure out how to load a data object within a Class using a Linq query. I didn't mean to confuse you. The catchline should be catch which I changed. Sorry for the bad example. Class could be used as the root node in this example.